# Function that creates an object to count unique words from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a program that counts unique words in a string and assigns them to a key/value pair in an object. Here is what I have so far:

```
  function count(sentence) {
  var list = sentence.split(' ');
  var words = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for(var j = -1; j < list.length; j++) {
      if(list[i] !== list[j]) {
        words[list[i]] = 1;
      } else {
        words[list[i]] += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return wordCount;
}
var display = count('ask a question get a question');
console.log(display);
```

The console is giving me:

```
[object Object] {
  a: 1,
  ask: 1,
  question: 2,
  get: 1
}
```

It's not counting one of the a's. What am I doing wrong? Couldn't find anything related with objects.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using 2 for loops? I don't understand what you approach is here

Comment: Walk through your code. Talk through it. Explain it to a rubber duck, or someone sitting next to you. Trace through it in a debugger. Execute it on a piece of paper as if you were the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as posted doesn't run, instead of `return wordCount` you should have `return words`.

I don't know why you initialise *j* to -1, it just creates an additional loop as there is no element at -1.

Your logic breaks down because you are comparing each word in the list to every other word and if it doesn't match, you set its count to 1. If it does match, you increment the count.

But the next time the word doesn't match, its value is reset to 1 even if it was previously some other value. The word "question" has a value of 2 because it's the last word and doesn't have a chance to be reset.

Your logic is fundamentally broken, so a new algorithm is required. A more common approach is to go over the words once and, as each word is encountered, if it's not already on the *words* object, add it and set its value to 1. If it's there already, increment the value.

E.g.

```js
function count(sentence) {
  var list = sentence.split(' ');
  var words = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (!(words.hasOwnProperty(list[i]))) {
      words[list[i]] = 0;
    }
    ++words[list[i]];
  }
  return words;
}
var display = count('ask a question get a question');
console.log(display);
```

This uses a *hasOwnProperty* test as you may encounter a word that is a standard property of an object. An alternative is to use:

```
var words = Object.create(null);
```

so that the *words* object has no inherited properties. Combined with some more recent functionality, it can be reduced to:

```js
function count(sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, word) {
    acc[word]? ++acc[word] : acc[word] = 1;
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
}
var display = count('ask a question get a question');
console.log(display);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating the issue. For starters, you only need a single loop through all the words. Think about if you were doing this yourself on paper, you'd only read through the sentence once to count how many instances of each letter.

As you loop through, you'd be checking to see if you have already come across that word by consulting your tally table (`words.hasOwnProperty`).

A better solution would be:

```
function count(sentence) {
    var list = sentence.split(' ');
    var words = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var word = list[i];
        if (words.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
            words[word]++;
        } else {
            words[word] = 1;
        }
    }
    return words;
}

var display = count('ask a question get a question');
console.log(display);
```

This gives:

```
{
    "ask":1,
    "a":2,
    "question":2,
    "get":1
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "*What am I doing wrong?*"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overcomplicating this with two loops. You only need to loop through the array of words once. If your `words` object has that key already, increment it. If it does not, set it to `1`.

```
  function count(sentence) {
    var list = sentence.split(' ');
    var words = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if(words[list[i]]) {
        words[list[i]]++;
      } else {
        words[list[i]] = 1;
      }
    }
    return words;
  }
  var display = count('ask a question get a question');
  console.log(display);
```

Comment: Answer times are so close